# Customize adapter to use custom font

Tags: java, android

I have both Custom Font example and a small List View example app. But I am unable to join them !!!

```
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    Typeface cFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/jcc.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(cFont);




<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:id="@+id/tv"
/>
```

and

```
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);

    String asim02 = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    String products[] = {
            "Apple" + asim02 +"Definition1", 
            "Orange" + asim02 +"Definition2",
            "Banana"+ asim02 +"Definition3", 
            "Onion"+ asim02 +"Definition4",  };

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.p_list,   products);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);



<TextView

        android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/p_list"
        />
```

Please help me customizing adapter to use custom font

Image of ProductList app https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15065300/ProductList.png

Here is the two example Apps http://www.mediafire.com/?scb3hjplb15yly5

Answer (score 7):

I do this by creating a CustomTextView.class

This would be my `list_item_layout.xml` :

```
<LinearLayout
    [...]

    android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.example.CustomTextView
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             [...]
             android:id="@+id/myCustomTextView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

N.B.: You have to point to your CustomTextView.class or else you will get an exception

This is the CustomTextView.class

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/yourfont.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }

}
```

You can apply this to `EditText`, `TextView`, `Buttons` etc

Comment: +1. I do this as well. It's a bit more verbose in XML but easier to maintain.

Comment: Boss, would you please see this. I am helpless... http://www.mediafire.com/?scb3hjplb15yly5

Comment: I uploaded the file to this location: http://ego.lu/Sample-ProductList-App.rar - The changes are the added `CustomTextView.java`file and a one line change in your list_item.xml (`<com.asdfg.productlist.CustomTextView`)

Answer (score 4):

Tacking off of @FoamyGuy's response, I viewed the your mediafire file response, but you didn't quite make a modified `arrayAdapter` class. I don't exactly have one of these file-sharing site accounts, so here's what should work:

in your `ProductList` activity replace your *adding items to listview code* with:

```
    // Adding items to listview
    Typeface cFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/jcc.ttf");
    adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.p_list, products, cFont);
```

then the custom class, which you must also insert:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <String> {

    private Typeface tf;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int resource;
    private int textViewResourceId;
    private String[] objects;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects, Typeface tf) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.tf = tf;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
        this.objects = objects;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);    
        }

        TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(textViewResourceId);
        text.setTypeface(tf);
        text.setText(objects[position]);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

if you need to see the full source folder, so that you're not making the same mistake, send me your email address and i'll send it to you.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to extend ArrayAdapter to have it set the typeface for you.

Here is an example of how:

```
public class FontArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    private Typeface mFont;
    FontArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, Typeface font){
        mFont = font;
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGoup parent){
        TextView tv;
        tv = (TextView) convertView;
        if(null == tv) {
            tv = new TextView(parent.getContext());
            tv.setTypeface(mFont);
        }

        tv.setText(getItem(pos));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your ArrayAdapter. Add context to your getAssets() --> context.getAssets()
Store the font file in the assets folder.

```
public class ArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<String> values2;
    Typeface font;


public ArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values,ArrayList<String> values2) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values2 = values2;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, parent, false);
    font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "arial.ttf");  

    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label2);
    textView.setTypeface(font);
}
return rowView;
}
}
```